# javascript problem with grails application on the server

Tags: java, javascript, grails, groovy

i have grails application. i use javascript files with this project.
    (I use javascript for calender)

problem: 
this calender works fine on my pc, but when i put my project on the server this calender doesn't work.

What can i do to keep this calender works on the server.

Note: operating system of my Pc and af server is linus ubuntu.

```
<g:javascript library="application"/>
<script src="/tandium.com/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tandium.com/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tandium.com/js/jquery.ui.datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" language="javascript1.2">

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.datetime').datetimepicker({dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss"});
        });
</script>
```

This calender works when user click on a textbox, calender appears, user then choose a date,  to appear in the textbox

Comment: What calendar are you using?  (an existing one, or a custom one?)  What error are you getting?  Have you looked at the code using something like Firebug?  Are all the files there and loaded?  Any 404 errors? How is the JS getting the calendar data? You're going to have to provide much more information to get this one answered, or to get a pointer in the right direction...

Comment: there is no error, yes all files there

Comment: i want to know if the problem is on the serve or on my application??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, now you have posted some code, I think I can see the issue..

You have hard-coded your context into your javascript links

```
<script src="/tandium.com/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tandium.com/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tandium.com/js/jquery.ui.datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can you try using the grails code to get a link like so:

```
<script src="${resource(dir:'js', file:'jquery-1.4.2.min.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${resource(dir:'js', file:'jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${resource(dir:'js', file:'jquery.ui.datetimepicker.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That should fix it... (you would have been getting 404 errors, and any javascript console would have shown you those files as missing)

Also, the line:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" language="javascript1.2">.2">
```

Has an extra `.2">` on the end of it (but that might be a cut/paste error posting here)